# How do I read the values of Excel dropdowns or checkboxes from c# or vb.net?

Tags: .net, excel, interop

I'm using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel to read the values of cells of a worksheet, but I'm unable to find information that shows how to read dropdowns, checkboxes and option buttons.

Thanks!

Comment: So, I'm thinking that I need to get the DropDowns collection, then get the individual DropDown, then get the LinkedCell of the selected dropdown to get the selected index, then go to the ListFillRange and select the index from the linkedCell?? Is this how it's done?

Comment: Is the drop down list populated by a reference to another sheet?

Comment: Nope, the list is on the same worksheet as the dropdown.

Comment: Here is some information that may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131040/how-to-get-the-value-in-an-excel-dropdown-using-c

Answer (score 3):

Apparently accessing the DropDowns collection directly is [verboten](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.dropdowns%28VS.80%29.aspx).  A workaround is to access the Validation property of the cell containing the dropdown, get it's formula and then parse out the location of the list.

```
Excel.Range dropDownCell = (Excel.Range)ws.get_Range("A1", "A1"); //cell containing dropdown
string formulaRange = dropDownCell.Validation.Formula1;
string[] splitFormulaRange = formulaRange.Substring(1,formulaRange.Length-1).Split(':');

Excel.Range valRange = (Excel.Range)ws.get_Range(splitFormulaRange[0], splitFormulaRange[1]);
for (int nRows = 1; nRows <= valRange.Rows.Count; nRows++) {
    for (int nCols = 1; nCols <= valRange.Columns.Count; nCols++) {
         Excel.Range aCell = (Excel.Range)valRange.Cells[nRows, nCols];
     System.Console.WriteLine(aCell.Value2);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this answer is a bit wrong as it talks about the validation of a cell and the OP seems to be asking to access values of MSForms.ComboBox, DropDown, etc.. not cell validation dropdowns.

Comment: this works if I have a simple range. What if I have this formula? =IF($A9<>"",INDIRECT(INDIRECT("Inventory!D" & MATCH(A9&C9,Inventory!A:A,0)))). I've been scratching my head I still couldn't get the range. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of head-scratching, I got the following to work *for dropdowns only*. I've also got a similar-but-not-identical solution for RadioButtons, but have not tried checkboxes.

This wasn't made any easier by Interop returning a System.Object where one would expect an array (VS debugger tells me it's technically a `System.Object[*]` - but whatever that is, I can't parse it like an array), or the `ControlFormat.List[]` array being 1-indexed. hooray!

The below code assumes an open workbook and the name of the target dropDown

```
Worksheet worksheet = (Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets[worksheetName];

var control = worksheet.Shapes.Item(dropdownName).ControlFormat;
var vl = GetDropdownList(control);

var targetIndex = IndexOfMatch(targetValue, vl);
control.Value = targetIndex;


// control.List returns a System.Object that may indeed be an array, but it's hard to parse in that format
// let's loop through it, explicitly casting as we go
private List<string> GetDropdownList(ControlFormat control)
{
    var newList = new List<string>();
    // haw! the Excel control-list is one-indexed! And the last item is equal to the count-index.
    for (int i = 1; i <= control.ListCount; i++)
    {
        newList.Add((string)control.List[i]);
    }

    return newList;
}

private int IndexOfMatch(string targetValue, List<string> vals)
{
    int indexMatch = vals.IndexOf(targetValue);

    // the Excel target is 1-indexed, so increase by one
    return ++indexMatch;
}
```

I would much rather prefer to do this in the OpenXmlSDK -- but d****d if I can figure out how to do it. I can find the DataValidation attached to the cell, parse the worksheet and cells it points to, get their SharedString values from the SharedStringTable -- but no matter what I do, I can't write any data back. Feh.

**Exel**: *From hell's heart I stab at thee.*

Answer (score 0):

```
string selectedText = myDropDown.get_List(myDropDown.ListIndex);
```

Comment: This gives me an error: "Public member 'get_list' on type 'DropDown' not found.