# How to get the value in an Excel dropdown using C#

Tags: excel

I am looking for code to open and read an Excel file, any version of Excel, including 2010.  One of my columns has a dropdown in it.  I need to get the value of the selected item in the dropdown.  I would eventually want to populate these values into a business object.

If anyone has some code to share please let me know.

I am using C# and Visual Studio 2010.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this an ActiveX drop down or a Forms dropdown?

Comment: I wasn't aware that there were both? Have you got code for both?  I assume forms dropdown?

Comment: A forms dropdown is much easier, because it can have a cell link that holds the value, so all you need to do is refer to the cell.

Comment: I've got a solution that also allows setting the value over @ http://stackoverflow.com/a/8521399/41153

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know the VBA for both the ActiveX combo and the forms dropdown, and based on that, I can give you some very inexpert notes for c# for the forms dropdown, the combo eludes me as yet.

Working with notes from: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302084

```
//Get a new workbook.
oWB = (Excel._Workbook)(oXL.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Docs\\Book1.xls"));
//3rd Sheet
oSheet = (Excel._Worksheet)oWB.Sheets.get_Item(3);

//This will return an index number
var i = oSheet.Shapes.Item("Drop Down 1").ControlFormat.Value;
//This will return the fill range
var r = oSheet.Shapes.Item("Drop Down 1").ControlFormat.ListFillRange;
oRng = oSheet.get_Range(r);
//This will return the value of the dropdown, based on the index
//and fillrange
var a =oRng.get_Item(i).Value;

//Just to check
textBox1.Text = a;
```

This may help with an ActiveX combo, but I have only half got it to work:

```
using MSForm = Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.Forms;

<...>
Excel.OLEObject cbOLEObj = (Excel.OLEObject)workSheet.OLEObjects("ComboBox1");
MSForm.ComboBox ComboBox1 = (MsForm.ComboBox) cbOLEObj.Object; 
Console.WriteLine(ComboBox1.Text);
```

From: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/66/10117559/excel-get-value-from-a-combobox.aspx

Comment: Does it advance Stackoverflow to vote down the sole answer to a question without adding some comments?

Comment: Edit your answer so that I vote it up again.  Sorry for this.

Comment: No problem. I can see it could deserve a down vote, in which case a note would be useful. It is also quite easy to down vote an answer when trying to do something else.

Comment: Two hints for this answer: a) To find out the shape name, right-click the dropdown, the name will appear in the top left (I couldn't get it another way) and b) 
this: oRng = oSheet.get_Range(r); will only work if the lookup area is on the same sheet.