# How to read Comboboxes Value from Excel using C#

Tags: c#, excel, combobox

In my application I have a requirement to create an excel file contains several combos.I have created upto that.
[image]

Now I have to read those combo's value from excel.
I have found a link to read from excel [Read From Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131040/how-to-get-the-value-in-an-excel-dropdown-using-c-sharp)

But In my code I have found this..

[image]

[image]

Here is my code

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application oXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook oWB;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet oSheet;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range oRng;

//Get a new workbook.
oWB = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook)(oXL.Workbooks.Open("C:\\TopicUpload_2017October14.xls"));
//3rd Sheet
oSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet) oWB.Sheets.get_Item(1);

 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.DropDowns allDropDowns = oSheet.DropDowns(Type.Missing);
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.DropDown oneDropdown = allDropDowns.Item("2");
```

Now how can I get selected text of this dropdown.. When I inspect I got

```
oneDropdown.ListCount = 5.0; // items count of second drop down, which is true
```

But could not able to get selected text.

```
oneDropdown.Text
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching , I'm able to get it.

```
#region Read value from excel combobox
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application oXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook oWB;
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet oSheet;
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range oRng;

                    //Get a new workbook.
                    oWB = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook)(oXL.Workbooks.Open("C:\\TopicUpload_2017October14.xls"));
                    //3rd Sheet
                    oSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)oWB.Sheets.get_Item(1);

                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.DropDowns allDropDowns = oSheet.DropDowns(Type.Missing);
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.DropDown oneDropdown = allDropDowns.Item("1"); // first combo
                    string selectedText = oneDropdown.get_List(oneDropdown.ListIndex); 
    #endregion
```