# Angular Js UI-Grid excel download along with dropdown in Excel file

Tags: jquery, angularjs, excel, ui-grid

I have implemented excel download option for Angular JS Ui-Grid, Now my requirement is to display drop-downs in the excel wherever we have drop-downs in grid. Excel drop-downs should be populated with the same data as we have in grid along with selected value.

Comment: you have your task, so what do you need from us?

Comment: I found and alternate option using ClosedXML.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39503281/how-to-assign-a-list-to-a-celldropdown-format-in-closedxml-while-exporting-to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39503281/how-to-assign-a-list-to-a-celldropdown-format-in-closedxml-while-exporting-to