# How do I read the values of Excel dropdowns using .net?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, interop, dropdown

i using interop excel but im unable to get the dropdown data from excel file.
Can anyone help me in getting drop down data and also to which dropdown is assigned

Comment: I think this question here explains it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27606170/how-to-read-excel-list-elements-data-validation-using-c-sharp-excel-interop

Comment: Ya but how do i read dropdown without giving cell